# general definition of concavity, mean-preserving spread and concavity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

The usual definition of concavity is: for any $x_1$ and $x_2$ and any $t\in[0,1]$, $$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\geqslant tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2).$$ I am wondering how to generalize this definition to more than 2 points:

$$f(\sum^{n}_{i=1}t_ix_i)\geqslant \sum^{n}_{i=1}t_if(x_i)$$ $$where \sum ^{n}_{i=1}t_i=1.$$
Then $f$ is concave.

For the 3 point case, if I have $$f(t_1x_1+t_2x_2+(1-t_1-t_2)x_3)\geqslant t_1f(x_1)+t_2f(x_2)+(1-t_1-t_2)f(x_3)$$ I want to find $x_4$ such that $$t_1f(x_1)+t_2f(x_2)\geqslant (t_1+t_2)f(x_4).........(1)$$
and $$f((t_1+t_2)x_4+(1-t_1-t_2)x_3)\geqslant f(t_1x_1+t_2x_2+(1-t_1-t_2)x_3).........(2)$$
then we  can write $$f((t_1+t_2)x_4+(1-t_1-t_2)x_3)\geqslant (t_1+t_2)f(x_4)+(1-t_1-t_2)f(x_3)$$
and now by the two-point definition of concavity, I can say $f$ is concave.

Now if my $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, to get (2) we need $$(t_1+t_2)x_4 \geqslant t_1x_1+t_2x_2$$  i.e.,$$x_4 \geqslant \frac{t_1}{t_1+t_2}x_1+\frac{t_2}{t_1+t_2}x_2.......(3) $$
And to get (1), we need $$ \frac{t_1}{t_1+t_2}f(x_1)+\frac{t_2}{t_1+t_2}f(x_2)\geqslant f(x_4) .......(4) $$
How to prove the existence of such a $x_4$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$? I want to apply the fact "A real differentiable function is concave if and only if its derivative is monotonically decreasing", which uses the Mean value theorem, but a continuous and strictly increasing function may not be differentiable?

> The context is, I have a distribution $x_t$ whose mean/expectation is
>   c, and I know $f(c)\geqslant\ E[f(x_t)]$, I want to prove that $f$ is
>   concave.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: The generalization I think you're referring to is called Jensen's Inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Comment: @charlestoncrabb hi thanks, I know Jensen's inequality, but that is in another direction, if $f$ is concave, then ..., but here we have the inequality condition and want to show concavity. If I were to use contrapositive,  suppose not concave, but a function can be neither concave nor convex....

Comment: @charlestoncrabb, contrapositive seems to work, but why the definition of Jensen's inequality is only one way? Is it actually an if and only if statement?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're trying to prove? If you are given that $f$ is concave, then by definition this means $-f$ is convex, to which you can apply Jensen's inequality.

Comment: hi, I am given the inequality E[f(x)]<=f(E[x]), and want to prove that $f$ is concave.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is not concave, can I say then E[f(x)]<=f(E[x]) should not be true so we have a contradiction? I am not sure about this point because  Jensen's inequality seems to imply one direction only.

Comment: So, you've just jumped from the real-valued function version to the measure theory version, in which "$x$" plays a very different role. Perhaps you should describe the problem as it is in the context of your class

Comment: Specifically, are you given that $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]\leq f(\mathbb{E}[x])$ for all $x$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37210/discussion-between-bob-and-charlestoncrabb).

Comment: Yes, I think so. But the context of my question is not measure based, $x_i$ is just an sequence and $x_t$ is a arbitrary constant.